# Custom Gorm preloading does not fetch data

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a query that fetches rows from `jobs` table and its author (each job has an `author`), but I want to select specific fields.

```
type User struct {
    ID         uint      `gorm:"primarykey" json:"-"`
    UUID       uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid not null" json:"-"`
    Email      string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"email"`
    Name       string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"name"`
    AvatarURL  string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"avatar_url"`
    Provider   string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"provider"`
    ProviderID string    `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"-"`
    Jobs       []Job     `json:"-"`
}

type Job struct {
    ID      uint   `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    Title   string `gorm:"type:varchar(255); not null" json:"title"`
    Content string `gorm:"not null" json:"content"`
    UserID  uint   `json:"-"`
    User    User   `json:"author"`
}

func (jobRepo repository) FindAll() ([]entity.Job, error) {
    var jobs []entity.Job

    if dbc := jobRepo.db.Preload("User", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Select("Name", "Email")
    }).Find(&jobs); dbc.Error != nil {
        return nil, dbc.Error
    }

    return jobs, nil
}
```

The custom preload does not behave as desired. If **I do not specify concrete fields**, the query **works** and returns everything. **Otherwise**, If I specify some fields, it returns nothing.

Comment: did you try it with all lower case letters, like `db.Select("name", "email")`?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same result.

Comment: Based on the example in the provided link, maybe you need to specify a table, like `db.Select("users.name", "users.email")`.
https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Custom-Preloading-SQL

Comment: Yeah. I did try this as well, does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you didn't select primary key. Add "ID" into select clause:

```golang
func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Select("ID", "Name", "Email")
}
```

Otherwise GORM doesn't know how to join users to jobs.

Comment: Seems to be working. I've accepted your answer and the bounty award will be received within 7 hours. Appreciate it, thanks!